# M2M attribute error with FOO_set.all() and FOO not a queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

Having a problem with a M2M related queryset:
simplified model is

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   category = models.ManyToManyField(
   Category, blank=True, null=True, related_name="categorytest")
```

I usually do related queries using related name (which works fine here no problem) yet I wanted to try "set_all()" in this case.
Say I do:
elecs = Category.objects.get(name="Electronics")
then:
elecs.product_set.all()
I get AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product_set'. I am a bit surprised because this is an error that happens when using a queryset instead of a model instance yet, if a confirmation was needed, a type(elecs) gives me <class 'store.models.Category'>.
I migrated/erased db multiple times, no change.
Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Since you set `related_name='categorytest'`, it is `elecs.categorytest.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the name of the relation in reverse with the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). Since you set `related_name='categorytest'`, you thus access these with:

```
elecs.categorytest.all()
```

But likely using `categorytest` is not a good idea. It might be better to specify this for example as `related_name='products'`.

Comment: ok, so what you say is that putting a related name "kills" the set_all() mechanism? They don't coexist right ?

Comment: @mdc123: by default for the related name, it uses `modelname_set`, so in this case that would be `product_set`. But since you set a different name, the name of the relation is thus different.

Comment: Yup, just removed related name and migrated now working. Thanks Willem